# speed up slow count in a 2 millions rows table

Tags: mysql, large-data-volumes

i have a Mysql table which has 2 millions rows.
The size is 600Mb.

this query take 2 seconds.
I don't know how to speed it up. The table is already in a Myisam format.
I don't know if i reached the limit of the slowness of a select count.

```
SELECT COUNT(video) FROM yvideos use index (PRIMARY) WHERE rate>='70' AND tags LIKE '%;car;%'
```

Thanks all

Comment: Is 'rate' stored as a numeric value? You could try WHERE rate>=70 instead of WHERE rate>='70' because the numeric comparison should be faster.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be optimised.

Firstly, you are doing a full scan with `LIKE`, because MySQL can not use an index with variable left part (it's possible for `';car;%'`, but not for `'%;car;%'`).

Secondly, MySQL (in most cases) doesn't use more than one index for a `SELECT`, so if you have two separate indexes for `rate` and `tags`, only one will be used.

So to deal with these things I advice to:
1. use a fulltext index for `tags` column,
2. replace one query with two separate queries and "glue" result with `INNER JOIN` (equals to `WHERE ... AND ...` in this case).

So in the end:

```
SELECT t1.* FROM
    (SELECT * FROM yvideos WHERE rate >= 60) t1
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT * FROM yvideos WHERE MATCH (tags) AGAINST ('+car +russia -usa' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) t2
USING (id);
```

[Live example on SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a85943/2/0).

Execute `EXPLAIN` for this query and take a look at a plan. Now there is no full scan, all filtering are done using indexes.

For more information about boolean fulltext searches you can read [a documetation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-boolean.html).

BTW, fulltext indexes are supported in both InnoDB and MyISAM now, so you can decide about an engine.